# TFS customization : How to customize the Burndown Chart and Thumbnail in the Team Web Access?

Tags: .net, tfs

How can i customize the burndown chart and the relevant thumbnail in the Team web access? The current appearance is shown in followig images.

I want to use Column charts instead of area chart currently used. I may need further customization but this area to column chart trick will help the rest.

I have edited the "Sprint Burndown" report chart in the report server hoping that it would affect the team web access chart, but it doesn't.

Any idea is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not currently possible. That being said there is a hard way: http://pascoal.net/2013/05/team-foundation-task-board-enhancer-version-7-released/

Answer (score 0):

Your `Team Web Portal` access your reports on Sharepoint in order to visualize report.
I suggest you to follow theses steps :

1. Access report on your `Sharepoint` hierarchy
2. Select report `BurnDownChart`, select  link `open the report in Microsoft Excel`
   (Remark : spreadsheet is connected to the Analysis Services cube )
3. Modify your report
4. Now you can `publish` (Menu tab of Excel) to your dashboard by selecting `Excel Services`
   (Remark : Excel Services caches the report, select reload the workbook on report).

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649552.aspx